# Using Memory Mapping or Unlocked Stream Operation?

Tags: c, linux, posix, memory-mapped-files

I am working on a FUSE implementation for FAT32 under Linux (I know this is already available in the Linux Kernel, but this is a school assignment).
The FAT32 filesystem is created with the `mkfs.msdos` command, which I will later map into memory with `posix_madvise`, or use an unlocked stream by means of `posix_fadvise`.

I am not sure what should I base my choice on, I mean, what the pros and cons of each method are (in terms of performance, memory usage, etc). I have seen a few examples out there which combine the use of `madvise` with `mmap`, but no information was provided as to whether `fadvise` should be used with `mmap` too, or, to start with, the difference between the `fadvise`/`madvise` and POSIX implementations `posix_fadvise`/`posix_madvise`.

Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to limit yourself to ~2.5 GB filesystems or requiring a 64-bit machine, your choices are to use `mmap` and dynamically manage what part of the filesystem you keep mapped, or use normal read/write operations. I would probably go for the latter. `mmap` is overrated as a performance optimization, and has drawbacks like filling up your virtual address space, so I would tend to only use `mmap` when you really need to treat a file as memory - for instance, storing process-shared synchronization objects, executable code, or large data you want to feed to an API that only accepts in-memory data (for example, `qsort`).